# how to make jqgrid group headers highlight on hover

Tags: jqgrid, header, hover, highlight

Using jQuery and themerolled jquery-ui, I have a jqgrid with columns under a few group headers.  Each of the column headers show the highlight color when hovered as expected, but the group headers never highlight when hovered.  Can jqgrid group headers highlight when hovered?
Here's the code in question.

```
$(gridnm).jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
    useColSpanStyle: true, 
    groupHeaders:[
        {startColumnName: 'fld00', numberOfColumns: 4, classname: 'colheader', titleText: '<b>Incoming Totals</b>'},
        {startColumnName: 'fld04', numberOfColumns: 3, classname: 'colheader', titleText: '<b>Unanswered Totals</b>'},
        {startColumnName: 'fld07', numberOfColumns: 3, classname: 'colheader', titleText: '<b>Outgoing Totals</b>'},
        {startColumnName: 'fld10', numberOfColumns: 3, classname: 'colheader', titleText: '<b>All Totals</b>'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem?

Comment: @Mark sorry, it did not.